# iOS: What is CGRect doing when I see strange calculated values during debugging?

Tags: ios, cgrect, cgrectmake

I'm trying to resolve a spacing issue while drawing to a PDF. In debugging, I am watching the method that constructs a rectangle for my string (see below). As I watch the values in the debugger, they go from nice float values (ie., 30.0) to what you see in the image below, before the method returns its values. What is going on? Why, for example, does x become 1.4013e - 45?

```
    CGRect renderingRect = CGRectMake(kBorderInset + kMarginInset + widthOfPrevious,    kBorderInset + kMarginInset + 50.0 + heightOfPrevious,stringSize.width, stringSize.height);

    return renderingRect;
```

Please see the value for renderingRect:

[image]

Comment: what data types are the constants? are they floats?

Comment: are you sure that your computation of the arguments of CGRectMake does not return non-round numbers?

Comment: Yes, the constants are floats. @Gabro, this is what I am trying to figure out. Somewhere, in one of my string-rectangles, extra space is getting added and it is not character whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`CGRectIntegral`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectIntegral) as shown below to round the floating point values to nearest smallest integers as shown below.

```
CGRect renderingRect = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(kBorderInset + kMarginInset + widthOfPrevious, kBorderInset + kMarginInset + 50.0 + heightOfPrevious,stringSize.width, stringSize.height));
```

Comment: @ABC Thank you, but this apparently is not the source of my problem.

Comment: @cmac, If you do this, are you seeing that issue? Ideally this should fix it.